# Transitive, reflexive and symmetric closures of relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

I have this problem I'm trying to solve.

Given is a set $X$ and a relation $r$ on $X$. For an equivalence relation $c$ on $X$ we say that $c$ is *produced* by r, if $r \subseteq c$ and for all equivalence relations $d$ on $X$ with $r \subseteq d$ it follows that that $c \subseteq d$.

(1) Let $s$ be the transitive-reflexive closure of $r$. Show that: If $r$ is symmetric, then $s$ is symmetric.
(2) Show that there is at most one equivalence relation that is *produced* by $r$.

**My solution attempts:**

(1) Let $x,y \in X$ and $(x,y) \in s$. If $(x,y) \in r$, then also $(y,x) \in r$, because $r$ is symmetric and because $r \subseteq s$, we have $(y,x) \in s$. If $(x,y) \not \in r$ and $x=y$, then clearly $(y,x) \in s$, because $s$ is reflexive. If $(x,y) \not \in r$ and $x \not=y$, then there is $z \in X$ such that $(x,z) \in r$ and $(z,y) \in r$. But since $r$ is symmetric, also $(z,x) \in r$ and $(y,z) \in r$ and because $s$ is transitive, also $(y,x) \in s$.

(2) Let $c,e$ be equivalence relations *produced* by $r$. It follows that $r \subseteq c$ and $r \subseteq e$. Since for all equivalence relations $d$ on $X$ with $r \subseteq d$, we have $c \subseteq d$ and $e \subseteq d$, we must also have $c \subseteq e$ and $e \subseteq c$. Therefore, we must have $c=e$.

I'm sure there are some mistakes. So I'd be very glad if you could point them out. I'd also appreciate if you could propose an alternative proof.

Comment: I think the only problem is that, in (1), from $(x,y) \in s$ it follows that there exist $z_1, \ldots, z_k$ such that $z_1 = x$, $z_k=y$ and $(z_i,z_{i+1}) \in r$ (you have this with $k=3$). So it's just a mater of elaborating a bit more...

Comment: Thank you, I'll will correct that. What do you think of (2)?

Comment: (2) it's ok. By the way, you're asked to prove that there exists at most one equivalence relation *produced* by each binary relation $r$ on $X$; it is also true that there exists always one, and so there exists one and only one. (Notice that $X^2$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.)